# SPARQL query failing to match literal on Pubchem RDF data

Tags: sparql, virtuoso

I have loaded part of the PubChem RDF data in Virtuoso and am trying to use SPARQL to query it, through iSQL.
While the following query works:

```
SELECT ?syno ?type ?value 
WHERE {    
    ?syno sio:is-attribute-of <http://rdf.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubchem/compound/CID1829049> .    
    ?syno rdf:type ?type .    
    ?syno sio:has-value ?value .       
} LIMIT 10;
```

I am not able to get any results for a query like (the value being taken from one of the above results):

```
SELECT ?syno
WHERE {?syno sio:has-value "AC1LXI26"};
```

In the previous case, I am simply trying to match a litteral.
Do I need to build an extra index? Is exact text match not supported in Virtuoso?

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem by simply adding `@en` at the end of the query string!

```
SELECT ?syno
WHERE {?syno sio:has-value "AC1LXI26"@en};
```

Comment: It's unfortunate that the data uses a language tagged literal there, since the text arguably isn't actually English text.  It looks like a plain literal would have been appropriate.  Don't forget to accept your answer.